# Add unix user to postfix maillogs

Tags: linux, email, centos, postfix-mta, spam

I am using CentOS 6, and postfix mail server, from postfix mail log, I want to see which Linux user has sent specific email, is it possible? How can this be done?

I need this to prevent spam from our mailservers, by one of our users. I need to figure out which user, and what script.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know which email you are looking for (you should know its ID from the message header), you can simply find it in postfix mail log located in /var/log/mail.log - just look for the message ID in the log.

Comment: no, i don't have mail headers and email, but i can probably find mail id, simply from any message how can i find user, when i have mail ID? May be you can advise how to find email header?